# how to get value from another table by their id's from another table?

Tags: mysql

Documents table (req1-7 are id's of requirements from another table)

```
| document_id | document_name | document_amount | req_1 | req_2 | req_3 | req_4 | req_5 | req_6 | req_7 |
|      1      |  Diploma      |      40         |   1   |  3    |    4  |     4 |    6  |  7    |  8    |
```

Requirements table

```
| requirement_id | requirement_name |
|    1           | 1 x 1 picture    |
|    2           | 2 x 2 picture    |
|    3           | Registration form|
|    4           | Clearance        |
|    5           | Medical cert     |
|    6           | xray result      |
|    7           | excuse letter    |
|    8           | affidavit        |
|    9           | comsoc clearance |
```

expected result is similar to the documents table but the the requirements names a displayed with the corresponding value of their id's .

I want to know the correct syntax to query those

So far my query is:

```
SELECT * FROM document_tbl 
            WHERE requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4,requirement5,requirement6,requirement7
            IN (
                SELECT requirement_name FROM requirements_tbl WHERE requirement_id=requirement1,requirement2,requirement3,requirement4,requirement5,requirement6,requirement7 )";
```

But I screwedup somehow. Thanks in advance for the help. I would appreciate it.

Comment: What does it have to do with PHP?

Comment: What output do you get with this query?

Comment: This is an inefficient way to write requirements. I'd recommend you to normalise your database. Refer to this: http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization

Comment: @phil652 the error I'm getting is I have an incorrect syntax with my query I'm playing around those query I research from other sites but seemed not to work with mine.

Comment: Maybe you can show the error you are getting and we can help

Comment: Join Requirements table with Documents table eight 8 times but it will be very sloooow.

Comment: @Ibu It says that I have an error in my sql syntax.

Comment: This will require 7 join statements to get the results and will be returned in 7 rows. As mentioned in the above comments a better way would be to have an intermediate table which has 2 columns, document_id and req_id. document_id is not in the current table structure but I suggest creating it.

Comment: How is that possible @MohamedYasin can you show me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
SELECT d.document_id,
   d.document_name,
   d.document_amount,
   r1.requirement_name AS req_1,
   r2.requirement_name AS req_2,
   r3.requirement_name AS req_3,
   r4.requirement_name AS req_4,
   r5.requirement_name AS req_5,
   r6.requirement_name AS req_6,
   r7.requirement_name AS req_7
FROM documents    AS d,
   requirements AS r1,
   requirements AS r2,
   requirements AS r3,
   requirements AS r4,
   requirements AS r5,
   requirements AS r6,
   requirements AS r7
WHERE d.req_1 = r1.requirement_id
   AND d.req_2 = r2.requirement_id
   AND d.req_3 = r3.requirement_id
   AND d.req_4 = r4.requirement_id
   AND d.req_5 = r5.requirement_id
   AND d.req_6 = r6.requirement_id
   AND d.req_7 = r7.requirement_id
```

and so on.

Comment: This works @MartynasTumas. But as they've told above. It processes the outputs in a slow manner however it gives the accurate result. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Intermediate table (document_requirements)

```
| document_id | requirement_id |
|      1      |  1             |
|      1      |  3             |
|      1      |  4             |
|      1      |  6             |
|      1      |  6             |
|      1      |  7             |
|      1      |  8             |
```

Query

```
SELECT d.document_id,dr.requirement_id,r.requirement_name
FROM documents AS d
JOIN document_requirements AS dr ON (dr.document_id=d.document_id)
JOIN requirements AS r ON (r.requirement_id=dr.requirement_id)
WHERE d.document_id = 1;
```

Comment: can''t the requirements be displayed horizontally? @Mohammed Yasin ? And can't it be shown with their corresponding names?

Comment: That's probably possible with 7 sub selects but as mentioned by others above, this would be very inefficient. With this method you can still loop through the results and get the names as that is included in the query above as "r.requirement_name"

Comment: @Mohammed Yasin Do I have to create another table named document_requirements: If so what are tthe name of the columns it contain? Sorry for not replying. I was busy with school projects.

Comment: The additional table normalises the data. In case there is a document having more than 7 requirements it can be added as a row in document_requirements instead of being added as another column in the requirements table.
The document_requirements table has 2 columns. document_id and requirement_id

Comment: Wow ! accurate. But I had this last question. What if I had less than 7 requirements can it be displayed into a table in HTML by their names? Because that long query given above is not flexible, it does not display the data into the HTML table if the other fields have no value or even NULL.

Comment: The number of rows returned by this query will be equal to the number of rows

Comment: The number of rows returned by this query will be equal to the number of requirements for the document